# How to set the camera pose in Open3D correctly?

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, visualization, open3d

Hi I am a beginner of Open3D, how can I change the camera's view to get different perspectives for the object in the scene? The final goal is to render a video from a certain perspective.

I tried different methods but every time when the visualization windows starts it remains the same view.

```
while True:
    mesh.vertices = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(vertices)
    mesh.compute_vertex_normals()
    vis.update_geometry(mesh)
    vis.poll_events()

    # Update the visualization

    ctr = vis.get_view_control()
    camera_params = ctr.convert_to_pinhole_camera_parameters()
    K = np.eye(4) 
    K[:3, :3] = np.array([[0,1,0],
                         [1,0,0],
                         [0,0,-1]])
    K[:3, -1] = np.array([10,10,10])
    camera_params.extrinsic = K
    ctr.convert_from_pinhole_camera_parameters(camera_params)

    vis.update_renderer()
```

[image]

Comment: OK I just find it is a bug of open3d 0.17, I downgrade to 0.16 then the problem solved

Comment: Thanks helped me out a ton. Was running into a similar issue and downgraded to 0.16 and problem is gone @jjx